# How to get class .select2-search of select2 from select element ID?

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

Given the `id` of individual select element I interact with, I tried to traverse all way down to get class `.select2-search` of `select2` to use it in my function but has no luck.

```js
function hideSelect2Keyboard(ID) {
  var Select2Search = $('#' + ID).prev().find('.select2-drop').find('.select2-search');

  console.log(Select2Search);

  $(Select2Search + ' input, :focus,input').prop('focus', false).blur();
}

$("select").select2().on("select2-open select2-close", function() {
  var ID = $(this).attr('id');
  hideSelect2Keyboard(ID);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.4.5/select2.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.4.5/select2.min.js"></script>


<label for="Salutation">Salutation:</label>
<select class="" name="" id="Salutation">
  <option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
  <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
  <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
</select>

<label for="Gender">Gender:</label>
<select class="" name="" id="Gender">
  <option value="Female">Female</option>
  <option value="Male">Male</option>
  <option value="Transgender">Transgender</option>
</select>
```

There is no error in console but I could not get the class `.select2-search`. I tried query above in console show like this

[image]

The html structure after select element is converted to select2 is look like below:

[image]

That's mean I have select element ID, `#Salutation`, from here I wish to get class `.select2-search`.

What's wrong with it, how can I get class `.select2-search` from the given select ID? Thanks.

Comment: What do you exactly wants, I am not able to see `select2-search` class in html

Comment: With `$('#' + ID).prev()` you are selecting the `label` element right before the original `select` element - but the elements you are looking for are not _inside_ that label, so of course `.find` doesn’t find them in there.

Comment: @Ibrahimshaikh, this class is auot generated by select2, if you inspect the result code above, you will see that class.

Comment: @misorude the plain html structure is like this but after select element is converted to select2, the html structure is quite different that include the class I wish to get `.select2-search`.

Comment: if you want to get the class from id you can simply do,

`$('#your selectID').find('classname');`

or

`document.getElementById('selectID').className.split(/\s+/);//here you will get list of classes`

Comment: @Ibrahimshaikh thanks, I knew how `.find()` works, yet the ID is not a parent of class `.select2-search`. That's i try to find a way to traverse from ID to get class `.select2-search`.

Comment: The problem is, those `.select2-search` elements are removed from the place they are in, once you open the modified select field for the first time. They get moved to the very end of body in the given example.

Comment: @misorude that's ways I tried to query it to get that class, from the html structure shown in question. Thanks

Comment: _“The html structure after select element is converted to select2 is look like below”_ - and the structure _after_ you clicked into the field and the dropdown opens, is different. Those elements are _not_ in the place you’re looking for them any more at that point.

Comment: @misorude I wish to get it on drop down open event, from the html structure on open event. the structure it change on other event will not a matter :)

Comment: The structure changes as soon as you click to open the element, and your code runs only after that. Maybe you have more luck if you trigger it on the `select2:opening` event instead.

Comment: @HouyNarun please check if my answer helps

Comment: @AhmedFarahat thanks very much. Now I’m on the way home, I will check it and let you know :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select2 has an option called **dropdownCssClass** if you specify a unique value here for each select the parent div of the rendered html of select2 will have this css class and so you can access it and find elements inside easily, i would change the code to be like this

```
<label for="Salutation">Salutation:</label>
<select class="" name="" id="Salutation" data-selector='salutation'>
 <option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
 <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
 <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
</select>

<label for="Gender">Gender:</label>
<select class="" name="" id="Gender" data-selector='salutation'>
 <option value="Female">Female</option>
 <option value="Male">Male</option>
 <option value="Transgender">Transgender</option>
</select>
```

note that i added a data attribute for each select, then in your intialization code you can do this

```
$("select").each(function(){
  var selector = $(this).data('selector')
  $(this).select2({
    dropdownCssClass: selector
  }).on("select2-open select2-close", function() {
    hideSelect2Keyboard(selector);
  });
});
```

now each of the rendered selects will have a parent with the specified class
now you can select it a find inside it for example

```
var yourDiv = $('.salutation').find('.select2-search')
```

Comment: I have tested it, it's quite strange to me I never know that, yet it really works. Thanks so much for your help me on this :)